# Update PHP 7.3.1 to PHP 7.3.5

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have tried to install PHP 7.3.1 to PHP 7.3.5 I use this code:

```
apt-get install php7.3.5
```

When I do that it shows me this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package php7.3.5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.3.5'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.3.5'
```

I wonder what is the problem? I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: You are using Ubuntu Right? Which version 18.04?

Comment: Yes I do @HarishST

Comment: Are you talking about PHP 7.4.5, which is the current stable version?

Comment: Nope, php 7.3.1 to php 7.3.5

Comment: Why should you can't update to the latest version ? 7.3.17 or 7.4? Is there any specific requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You need to first see the following steps and go with these steps:

**Step 1:** Connect to your server via SSH and update your server OS packages.
**Step 2:** Install a Web Server like google chrome.
**Step 3:** Install Ondřej Surý's PPA.
**Step 4:** #important# Install PHP 7.2.
**Step 5:** Search and install specific PHP 7.2 extensions.
**Step 6:** Install most commonly used PHP extensions.
**Step 7:** Check the PHP installation.

Comment: I already did that, it already has php 7.3.1 BUT I need php 7.3.5

Comment: This answer explains the installation of PHP 7.2. The OP is not looking for this version of PHP to be installed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run `apt-get update`?

Try running `apt-get install php7.3` without the minor version.

If that also doesn't work you might need to use a PPA.

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install php7.3`

Comment: I did all that but it installed php 7.3.1 but I need php 7.3.5

Comment: Did you also run `sudo apt-get upgrade` and then tried to run the other commands?